# The structure of the limit set $w(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Im currently studying differential equations and dynamical systems, specifically from the book of Gerald Teschl. I have a question about limit sets.

> Def: The $w_{+}(x)$ (resp $w_{-}$) of a point $x$ is the set of those points $y$ for which there exists a sequence $t_n \to \infty $ (resp($t_n \to -\infty $)) such that $\Phi(t_n,x)\to y$, where $\Phi(t,x)$ denotes the flow of the system at time $t$ starting at $x$.

Now, the thing that confuses me is that the book continues proving lemmas/theorems about the set $w_{\sigma}(x)$, for example about its closure, invariance, compactness, connectedness and so on. Which tells me that this sets can be bigger than just a point. But, how can this set consist of more than one point? How can a solution/trajectory, have a limit on several points? In my logic, for example, $w_{+}(x)$ is either a point in the domain, or empty. Right? (I guess not..., but clarify please)

Comment: You can also have a limit cycle, a strange attractor like in the Lorenz system or something more complicated as limit set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps an example will help.

Consider the flow on the circle $S^1$ generated by the unit tangent vector field $v_{x,y} = \langle -y,x\rangle$. The time $t$ map $\Phi(t,x)$ of this flow is simply rotation of the circle through an angle of $t$ radians.

Given any $x,y \in S^1$, I can find an angle $t \in (0,2\pi]$ such that $\Phi(t,x)=y$. But since rotation through angle $2\pi$ is the identity map, it follows that $\Phi(t + 2 \pi n,x)=y$ for all integers $n \ge 1$. Since $t + 2\pi n \to \infty$, it follows that $y \in w_+(x)$. This is true for *every* $x,y \in S^1$.

So we've shown that $w_+(x)=S^1$ for *every* $x \in S^1$.

Comment: Just.. wow.  Thanks, it makes complete sense now. Why wouldnt the author give such an example i wonder. I have another small question, just answer yes or no if the explanation is too complicated. Does the omega limit set contain more than one point only if the orbit in question is periodic?

Comment: No, that's not true. There are many, many different kinds of examples, with many, many different behaviors for $w_+(x)$, including many other nonperiodic examples where $w_+(x)$ is the entire space.